# * projection with case class

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

So I was following: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.2/gettingstarted.html and now I'd like to use case classes instead of defining every model as a tuple.

So I have:

```
case class Character(id: Long, foreName: String, middleNames: String, lastName: String, age: Int)

//class Characters(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, Int)](tag, "characters")
class Characters(tag: Tag) extends Table[Characters](tag, "characters")
{
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def foreName = column[String]("forename")
  def middleNames = column[String]("middlenames")
  def lastName = column[String]("lastname")
  def age = column[Int]("age")

//  def * = (id, foreName, middleNames, lastName, age)
  def * = (id, foreName, middleNames, lastName, age) <> (Character.tupled, Character.unapply _)
}
```

But I get:

> Expression of type MappedProjection[Character, (Long, String, String,
>   String, Int)] doesn't conform to expected type ProvenShape[Characters]

But why is that? It's basically the same as: http://de.slideshare.net/rebeccagrenier509/slick-learn2 slide 7. Even if that is Slick 2 only, how can I achieve the same in Slick 3?

Comment: It looks like you want `extends Table[Character]`, not `extends Table[Characters]`.

Comment: @Shadowlands: Argh... make it an answer and I'll accept ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want `... extends Table[Character]`, not `... extends Table[Characters]`.